# How to load a huuuuuge string into a BigInteger in C# and not lose the ASCII encoding

Tags: c#, biginteger

I am using BigInteger.Parse(some string) but it takes forever and I'm not even sure if it finishes.

However, I can convert the huge string to a byte array and jam the byte array into a BigInteger constructor in very little time but it munges the original number stored in the string because of the endian issue with BigInteger and byte arrays.

Is there a way to convert the string to a byte array and put the byte array into the BigInteger object while preserving the original number stored in ASCII in the string?

```
String s = "12345";  // Some huge string, millions of digits.

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);  // very fast but the 12345 is lost 

// OR...
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse(s);  // Takes forever therefore unuseable.
```

Comment: You can't parse a string without parsing the string.

Comment: `it munges the original number stored in the string because of the endian issue with BigInteger and byte arrays` No; because bytes are not ASCII characters.  BigInteger uses bytes as numbers.

Comment: Yeah, endian-ness is the least of your problems with the `GetBytes` constructor.  You're passing a completely different type of data (an ASCII-encoded string) than what the constructor is expecting (a raw number).  Unfortunately, I don't think your problem is solvable.  You want to quickly parse a string that is megabytes long?  It shouldn't be a string in the first place.  If this data is coming from a file, for example, the routine reading the file should probably be directly converting the data to a big integer.  Complicated...I would start looking at hardcore math libraries...

Comment: Why are you converting your string to a BigInteger? Can you not do whatever you are trying to do on the string itself?

Comment: @DourHighArch I want to do math on the BigInteger. It's it's just a string that's not as possible.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, but I can convert it to a byte array in no time and then parse the byte array, yeah?

Comment: @nicomp It's not the conversion to byte[] that matters, as much as what else the `Parse` method is doing. I added a version that perfroms faster to my answer, about 5 timea faster, but I am curious how big your numbers are, I tested with 300k digits, and the original `Parse` took 18s, sure long but not forever :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir 20 million digits. I can load it from a text file into a StringBuilder object, then use ToString() to make a String object. That takes very little time. Then, calling the BigInteger.Parse sends it off into the weeds. Converting the 20M character string to a byte array and popping that into a BigInteger also takes no time, but the semantics of the original n umber are lost.

Comment: @nicomp At 20M digits, even my version will not be fast enough. Maybe a parallel one? Is using more cores an option? Unfortunately the conversion has to be made the  from the ASCII decimal  representation of the number has to be converted to binary, and this is how it has to be done.

Comment: AFAIK, C#'s BigInteger.Parse uses the naive method, multiplying by 10 and adding one digit at a time. If you want better speed, you need a divide-and-conquer algorithm, cf. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4710v1.pdf especially chapter 1.7. These algorithms are asymptotically faster, if the size is big enough.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  BigInteger.Parse("123") is naive but new BigInteger(new byte[] {1,2,3...} is blazingly fast. There should be a way to convert the string to a byte array then recover the semantics of the original ASCII number stored in the string before giving that byte array to BigInteger. At least, I think there should be a way.

Comment: Of course using a byte array is blazingly fast. I am talking about *parsing* a string of digits.

Comment: Parsing is, in this case, a base conversion from base 10 (decimal) to base 2 (binary). Parsing a hex string would be blazingly fast too. But not a string with a decimal representation.

Answer (score 5):

The `byte[]` representation of `BigInteger` has little to do with the ASCII characters. Much like the byte representation of an `int` has little to do with the ASCII representation of it.

To parse the number, each character must be converted to the digit value, and added to the previously parsed value multiplied by 10. That is probably why it's taking so long, and any version you write will probably not perform better. It has to do something like:

```
    var nr=0;
    foreach(var c in "123") nr=nr*10+(c-'0');
```

**Edit**

While it is not possible to perform the conversion by just converting to a byte array, the library implementation is slower then it has to be (at least for simple scenarios that do not need internationalization for example). Using the trick suggested by Rudy Velthuis in the comments and not taking into account hex formats or internationalization, I was able to produce a version which for 303104 characters runs ~5 times faster (from 18.2s to 3.75s. For 1 milion digits the fast method takes 47s, long, but it is a huge number):

```
public static class Helper
{
    static BigInteger[] factors = Enumerable.Range(0, 19).Select(i=> BigInteger.Pow(10, i)).ToArray();
    public static BigInteger ParseFast(string str)
    {
        var result = new BigInteger(0);
        var n = str.Length;
        var hasSgn = str[0] == '-';
        int j;
        for (var i = hasSgn ? 1 : 0; i < n; i += j - i)
        {
            long gr = 0;
            for (j = i; j < i + 18 && j < n; j++)
            {
                gr = gr * 10 + (str[j] - '0');
            }
            result = result * factors[j-i]+ gr;

        }
        if (hasSgn)
        {
            result = BigInteger.MinusOne * result;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, this would be crazy slow since the only built-in that can store this value is immutable.  The GC alone....

Comment: It can be done faster, but it requires you to write a divide and conquer algorithm for it. The big prblem with huge number is that you must multiply a huge number by 10 each time (and it grows). Divide this up by dividing the string in smaller pieces, parse these and then multiplying these first, scaled by the appropriate powers of 10. Then only the last multiplication will be huge, but the others will deal with smaller and smaller numbers. Conversion the other way around (from binary to decimal) improved creating huuuuuuge strings from many hours to a few minutes.

Comment: @zzxyz Checked the implementation, and in fortunately they have a builder version of the type, so they don't allocate a new one for each iteration, still for a very big number, the multiplication and addition will take a while since they are not hardware supported http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigNumber.cs

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Oh wow!  Since the default Parse() implementation is very interface driven to account for Culture info, this might actually be significantly faster.  Maybe :)

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Cool idea, the built-in implementation works as I described, so your version will probably perform much better

Comment: Yeah, I suppose if you're multiplying huge base2 numbers by 10 over and over, a tiny bit of parsing overhead isn't going to be a significant factor, is it?

Comment: @zzxyz Not at my PC right now, but I am intrigued, I will try to put together a faster version, it appears to be possible.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for the idea, implemented it, it's 5 times faster

Comment: @nicomp  I edited the answer, added a faster version of parse

Comment: @zzxyz Library version can in deed be made faster :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: it should be asymptotically faster, so the bigger the string, the bigger the gain (if you do this recursively down to a certain small size, say, integer size (9 digits)). But such routines often have a big overhead, so usually they're only faster over a certain size threshold.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: That is only a little bit "divide-and-conquer". I mean splitting a 20 milltion digit string into two 10 milltion digit strings, converting each and then putting them together, multiplying the high one with 10^x. If you do this recursively down (5 million, 2.5 million, etc.) until you hit integer size, you should be 20 times faster, especially for a 20 million digit string.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I thought about that version as well, my problem is that multiplication factors become an issue, right now I cache the `BigNumbers` that represent the factors, the way you suggest, I would need a factor with 1mil digits when I join the 1mil digit splits, I have not had time to see if that will not in itself be an issue.

Comment: BigInteger.Pow() should be pretty fast. And you can indeed cache powers of 10. But IME, multiplication factors do not become an issue and caching does not make a big difference. In my (Object Pascal + assembler based) implementation I use this and it is much faster than your or the naive method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163879/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-rudy-velthuis).